# Tensorflow: pass in integer dynamically?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, int, placeholder

I'm trying to use tf's dynamic_partition which is used like this:

```
tf.dynamic_partition(data=someTensor, partitions=lengthOfArticles, num_partitions=numPartitions, name="Partition_Data")
```

I want num_partitions to be dependent on the data in each run(), so I defined a placeholder:

```
numPartitions = tf.placeholder(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackedSeq2Seq.py", line 123, in <module>
    summedAttention = sumUp(eout.attention_values)
  File "stackedSeq2Seq.py", line 66, in sumUp
    partitioned = tf.dynamic_partition(data=someTensor, partitions=lengthOfArticles, num_partitions=numPartitions, name="Partition_Data")
  File "/Users/akilesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 423, in dynamic_partition
    num_partitions=num_partitions, name=name)
  File "/Users/akilesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 684, in apply_op
    attr_value.i = _MakeInt(value, key)
  File "/Users/akilesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 156, in _MakeInt
    (arg_name, repr(v)))
TypeError: Expected int for argument 'num_partitions' not <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int32>.
```

Is there any clever way around this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pass the number of partitions dynamically. According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_partition) `tf.dynamic_partition` expects an python integer not a tensor. This is because the number of elements in the list that is returned by `tf.dynamic_partitition` needs to be known statically.

Comment: I've read the documentation and realized it's not possible. Is there an other way to implement dynamic_partition such that it does?